# Error in rails saving attribute to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 models: User and UserLvl.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :user_lvl, primary_key: 'user_lvl_id', foreign_key: 'id'
end

class UserLvl < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Controller action

```
 def change_lvl
  @user.user_lvl = UserLvl.first
  @user.save
 end
```

`UserLvl.first` is returned fine,with `id` and all but it failes at the first line with : `"Column 'id' cannot be null"`

why is this happening?

EDIT:

schema.rb

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
 t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
 t.integer  "user_lvl_id"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "user_lvls", force: true do |t|
 [omited some information]
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Comment: show those errors with the attempt caused it. Of course #all wouldn't work.. But I don't understand #id.

Comment: What does your database schema for those two models look like? In particular, what id columns are in what tables and what are they called?

Comment: can you show db/schema.rb

Comment: Can you redefine what you meant by *with id and all* ?

Comment: Im sorry for not beeing punctual. By 'all' , I meant  all the other fields that are in UserLvl. Shortly the object is returned corectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a `belongs_to` association rather than a `has_one`, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_lvl
end
```

Your foreign key is placed in the `users` table, which makes `User` the associated model, that belongs to the `UserLvl`.